# Error during installation of omnetpp on MAC(5.6.1)

Tags: installation, omnet++, setenv

[image]I found couple of answers but none of them was helpful, I downloaded omnetpp for MAC (omnetpp-5.6.1-src-macosx.tar) if i open the IDE directly I get "“Omnetpp” is damaged and can’t be opened." I tried installing it like 5 times. I found that I should execute setenv, I got this error "Error: not a login shell -- run this script as 'source setenv' or '. setenv'"
Can someone please help me with the steps to install/use omnetpp? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests:

- first open a terminal window
- change to the omnetpp installation directory i.e. cd ~/omnetpp-5.6.1 or similar.
- source setenv
- ./configure
- make -j4
- omnetpp

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the "omnetpp-5.6.1" directory right in the home path: i.e. ~/Users/yourname

**Open the "doc" directory in "omnetpp-5.6.1" directory and there you can see an installation guide which helps you what to do step by step.** 
Do the instruction. be careful writing the command `./configure` it may not work. If it doesn't you should use `./configure WITH_TKENV=no WITH_QTENV=no` instead of that.
Also before you run `$ make` command in terminal you have to run `$ . setenv` .

I did the instruction but I couldn't run the software yet, then I noticed that the problem is my java version!
write:

```
$java -version
```

in your terminal it will show you the actual version your system is using, It must be java8 for running this software if it's not, try to downgrade or upgrade it to java8

I hope it helps you! GL!